# Is this a PL/SQL bug?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Here's an excerpt from some PL/SQL code that I believe demonstrates a PL/SQL bug:

```
if guid_ is null then
   dbms_output.put_line('guid_ is null: ' || guid_);
end if;
```

When these lines are executed, it prints

```
guid_ is null: 07D242FCC55000FCE0530A30D4928A21
```

I am on Oracle 11R2

```
select * from v$version;

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

I can reproduce this with the following types and anonymous block. Sorry for the length, but I believe I cannot shorten it any more:

```
create type tq84_t as table of varchar2(32);
/

create type tq84_o as object (
  dummy number(1),

  not final member procedure clear

) not final;
/

show errors

create type tq84_d under tq84_o (

  g varchar2(32),
  constructor function tq84_d return self as result,

  overriding member procedure clear


);
/
show errors


create package tq84_h as

    t tq84_t;

end tq84_h;
/
show errors



create package body tq84_h as
begin

  t := tq84_t();
end;
/
show errors

create type body tq84_o as

   member procedure clear is begin
      null;
   end clear;

end;
/

create type body tq84_d as

  constructor function tq84_d return self as result is
  begin

      g := sys_guid;
      return;

  end tq84_d;

  overriding member procedure clear is begin

      tq84_h.t.extend;
      tq84_h.t(tq84_h.t.count) := g;

      g := null;

  end clear;

end;
/
show errors


declare

  b  tq84_o;  -- Change to tq84_d ...

  guid_ varchar2(32);

begin

  b := new tq84_d;

  guid_ := treat(b as tq84_d).g;

  b.clear;

  if guid_ is null then
     dbms_output.put_line('guid_ is null: ' || guid_);
  end if;


end;
/

drop type tq84_t;
drop type tq84_d;
drop type tq84_o;
drop package tq84_h;
```

Note also, that when I change `b tq84_o` to `b tq84_d`, the error does not occur anymore.

Can someone verify if this is happening on other systems as well?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is yet, but changing `b tq84_o` to `b tq84_d` causes `guid_` to be not-null when the `if` condition is evaluated. adding an `else` statement that prints a similar statement confirms that.

Comment: I just realized that the bug is that `if guid_ is null` is evaluating to true, not that the `dbms_output` is returning a value when the variable should be null.

Comment: Furthermore, adding an `else` causes the version with `b tq84_o` to act as expected.

Comment: If You put the anonymous block from Your example in the procedure inside package, it will work correctly. And also adding else statement in my case is not solving the problem. Additionaly this behaviour is gone when You are changing some line tq84_d type's clear procedure and compiling the type. After if You compile the whole types and package again the "bug" is comming back. Anyway very interesting question You got my upvote, thanks for the question.

Comment: @Allan Adding an `else` does not change anything here. Are you using 11R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this is a bug. In the `IF` the variable `guid_` is not treated the same as in the the string concatenation for the `put_line`. What I find strange is that before the `b.clear`  statement the `is null` works:

```
declare
  b  tq84_o;  -- Change to tq84_d ...
  guid_ varchar2(32);
begin
  b := new tq84_d;
  guid_ := treat(b as tq84_d).g;

  if guid_ is null then
     dbms_output.put_line('before clear: guid_ is  null: ' || guid_);
  end if;

  b.clear;

  if guid_ is null then
     dbms_output.put_line('after clear: guid_ is null: ' || guid_);
  end if;
end;
/
```

Output:

```
after clear: guid_ is null: 07D43ACB728A2173E054A0481C66CF28
```

I workaround the problem when returning the GUID from a function:

```
declare
  b  tq84_o;  -- Change to tq84_d ...
  guid_ varchar2(32);
  function get_guid 
  return varchar2 is 
  begin 
    return treat(b as tq84_d).g;
  end;  
begin
  b := new tq84_d;
  guid_ := get_guid; -- treat(b as tq84_d).g;

  if guid_ is null then
     dbms_output.put_line('before clear: guid_ is  null: ' || guid_);
  end if;

  b.clear;

  if guid_ is null then
     dbms_output.put_line('after clear: guid_ is null: ' || guid_);
  end if;
end;
/
```

The above code does not go into neither of the `if guid_ is null`. So to me this proves it:

This is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an Oracle bug. I am seeing the same thing on our instance of Oracle Enterprise 11.2.0.3.0 (64bit).

After playing with it a little, it's pretty clear that the bug is in the `if` condition: `guid_ is null` is evaluating to true even though it contains a value.

---

My earlier comment regarding `else` no longer appears to be true. Either I inadvertently changed the test script in some way or the bug is somewhat unpredictable.

---

I seem to reliably make the `else` scenario work be following these steps:

1. Change the `if` to:

`if guid_ is null then
 dbms_output.put_line('guid_ is null: ' || guid_);
else
 dbms_output.put_line('guid_ is not null: ' || guid_);
end if;`

2. Run the script; the output returns the null message.
3. Change declaration from `tq84_o` to `tq84_d`.
4. Run the script; the output returns the not null message.
5. Change declaration back to `tq84_o`.
6. Run the script; the output returns the not null message.

My output from this process is:

```
guid_ is null: 07D41C8BCE696EA3E0539014190A7DA0
guid_ is not null: 07D41C8BCE7D6EA3E0539014190A7DA0
guid_ is not null: 07D41C8BCE916EA3E0539014190A7DA0
```

---

It looks like the corrected behavior has nothing to do with the `else`. If I simply take the original script and run it twice in the same session, it works incorrectly the first time and correctly the second time.

---

As @hol observed, this bug also goes away if the code is in a function or stored procedure. In my case, I changed the entire anonymous block to a procedure then ran the procedure and the bug did not occur.

Comment: On my installation, with an `else`, it still prints `guid_ is null: ...`.